# looking for help to use Registry in Windows with C/C++

Tags: windows, registry

i got this link for Registry in Windows

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt654040(v=vs.85).aspx#_api-ms-win-core-registry-l1-1-0.dll

but it is very hard to understand.

not able get more details

need help in this regard

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: i want to use Registry in Windows to store some required info...please provide some more info or some link where i can get more details...any example...how to create a Registry...how to update with the key..how to read..

Answer (score 0):

Cool. You can do something like this:

1. Open the registry using [RegOpenKeyEx function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724897(VS.85).aspx).
2. Query the value with [RegQueryValueEx function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724911(VS.85).aspx).
3. Store the value in a variable.
4. Finally close the registry using [RegCloseKey function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724837(VS.85).aspx)

Also this should be helpful to you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724256(VS.85).aspx